# To obtain Pearson type III parameters and shift value

Tags: distributions, maximum-likelihood, gamma-distribution

How to obtain Pearson type III parameters and shift value?

I am using R and if you can give me an instruction, it would be helpful.
I have used pearsonFitML function from PearsonDS package, but I can not force it to only check the values of the Pearson type III.

Comment: From what kind of information do you wish to compute these parameters?  Data drawn independently from such a distribution?

Comment: Actually, I have a set of data which are basically from waiting times inside the system.

Comment: I would really need to test the fit possibility of Pearson type III by having shift values and parameters.